# Can there be more than one stronghold in minecraft for ps4

Tags: ps4, minecraft-legacy-console

I have a seed I really like and I used an Ender eye to find the closest stronghold but it did NOT contain an end portal. I don't want to keep investing in this world if there is no working end portal somewhere.

Can there be more than one stronghold per world on PS4 Minecraft?

Comment: I believe I found the answer. The rest of the stronghold can be hidden.

Comment: It is important to note that in Legacy Console Editions, Eyes of Ender do not necessarily lead to and End Portal, only to the nearest Stronghold. https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Eye_of_Ender#Usage

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 strongholds per world in Minecraft Console Edition.

> Note that one of the End Portal Blocks already has an eye of ender in it. There is a limit of 128 strongholds per world (3 per world in Console Edition).

minecraft.gamepedia.com/Stronghold

Answer (score 1):

You will always have an end portal in every world you make. Either you haven't explorered the stronghold enough, (which I don't think is the case) Or you have another Stronghold in your map. Heck, you might have one anyways. I found several strongholds in one world when I used to play on the PC, so I believe that's the case.